# NullPointerException in binary search tree

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Each time I run it, I get a `NullPointerException`.

```
public StrongBuilder inorder() {
    return inorder(root);

}

private StringBuilder inorder(Node root) {
    StringBuilder val;
    if (root != null) {
        inorder(root.getLeft())

    }
    val = new StringBuilder().append(root.getValue().getAccountNumber()).append(root.getValue().getName());
    inorder(root.getRight());
    return val;
}
```

Can anyone help spot the error for me? Thanks.

Comment: Probably `root.getValue()` is `null`. But how would we know, you don't post the relevant code or stack trace.

Comment: can you share the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
val = new StringBuilder().append(root.getValue().getAccountNumber()).append(root.getValue().getName());
```

Eather this code returns null: root.getValue().getAccountNumber()
Or this is the problem: root.getValue().getName() - root.getValue() returns null.